# Can I run javascript before the whole page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to run a bit of javascript before the whole page has loaded. Is this possible? Or does the code start to execute on `</html>`?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Not only *can* you, but you have to make a special effort *not* to if you don't want to. :-)

When the browser encounters a classic `script` tag when parsing the HTML, it stops parsing and hands over to the JavaScript interpreter, which runs the script. The parser doesn't continue until the script execution is complete (because the script might do `document.write` calls to output markup that the parser should handle).

That's the default behavior, but you have a few options for delaying script execution:

1. Use JavaScript modules. A `type="module"` script is *deferred* until the HTML has been fully parsed and the initial DOM created. This isn't the primary reason to use modules, but it's one of the reasons:

   ```
   <script type="module" src="./my-code.js"></script>
   <!-- Or -->
   <script type="module">
   // Your code here
   </script>
   ```

   The code will be fetched (if it's separate) and parsed in parallel with the HTML parsing, but won't be *run* until the HTML parsing is done. (If your module code is inline rather than in its own file, it is also deferred until HTML parsing is complete.)

   This wasn't available when I first wrote this answer in 2010, but here in 2020, all major modern browsers support modules natively, and if you need to support older browsers, you can use bundlers like Webpack and Rollup.js.
2. Use the `defer` attribute on a classic script tag:

   ```
   <script defer src="./my-code.js"></script>
   ```

   As with the module, the code in `my-code.js` will be fetched and parsed in parallel with the HTML parsing, but won't be *run* until the HTML parsing is done. **But**, `defer` doesn't work with inline script content, only with external files referenced via `src`.
3. I don't think it's what *you* want, but you can use the `async` attribute to tell the browser to fetch the JavaScript code in parallel with the HTML parsing, but then run it as soon as possible, even if the HTML parsing isn't complete. You can put it on a `type="module"` tag, or use it instead of `defer` on a classic `script` tag.
4. Put the `script` tag at the end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag:

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <!-- ... -->
   <body>
   <!-- The document's HTML goes here -->
   <script type="module" src="./my-code.js"></script><!-- Or inline script -->
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   That way, even though the code is run as soon as its encountered, all of the elements defined by the HTML above it exist and are ready to be used.

   It used to be that this caused an additional delay on some browsers because they wouldn't start fetching the code until the `script` tag was encountered, but modern browsers scan ahead and start prefetching. Still, this is very much the third choice at this point, both modules and `defer` are better options.

The spec [has a useful diagram](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async) showing a raw `script` tag, `defer`, `async`, `type="module"`, and `type="module" async` and the timing of when the JavaScript code is fetched and run:

[image]

Here's an example of the default behavior, a raw `script` tag:

```css
.found {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<script>
    if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
        NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    }
    document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(p => {
        p.classList.add("found");
    });
</script>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

*(See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247) for details around that `NodeList` code.)*

When you run that, you see "Paragraph 1" in green but "Paragraph 2" is black, because the script ran synchronously with the HTML parsing, and so it only found the first paragraph, not the second.

In contrast, here's a `type="module"` script:

```css
.found {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<script type="module">
    document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(p => {
        p.classList.add("found");
    });
</script>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

Notice how they're both green now; the code didn't run until HTML parsing was complete. That would also be true with a `defer` `script` with external content (but not inline content).

*(There was no need for the `NodeList` check there because any modern browser supporting modules already has `forEach` on `NodeList`.)*

In this modern world, there's no real value to the `DOMContentLoaded` event of the "ready" feature that PrototypeJS, jQuery, ExtJS, Dojo, and most others provided back in the day (and still provide); just use modules or `defer`. Even back in the day, there wasn't much reason for using them (and they were often used incorrectly, holding up page presentation while the entire jQuery library was loaded because the `script` was in the `head` instead of after the document), something [some developers at Google](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41) flagged up early on. This was also part of the reason for the [YUI recommendation](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) to put scripts at the end of the `body`, again back in the day.

Comment: Or put it all in a function and put it in `<body onload="doIt()>"`.

Comment: @JustinLiu - The `load` event happens **very** late in the page load cycle, it's almost never best practice to wait to run your JavaScript until then. But yes, it is an option. I've overhauled the answer for 2020, btw.

Comment: Or you could use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
//doyour stuff
})`

Comment: @JustinLiu - Yup, see the last paragraph. :-) I've never seen any need to, but you can.

Comment: @JustinLiu - This is starting to be over the top. If you want to post an answer, please post an answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can run javascript code at any time. AFAIK it is executed at the moment the browser reaches the <script> tag where it is in. But you cannot access elements that are not loaded yet.

So if you need access to elements, you should wait until the DOM is loaded (this does not mean the whole page is loaded, including images and stuff. It's only the structure of the document, which is loaded much earlier, so you usually won't notice a delay), using the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event or functions like [`$.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in jQuery.

Comment: The DOMContentLoaded event will fire as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed, the load event will do it when all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.