# Reserved word 'script' embedded in id tag - id can't be referenced

Tags: javascript, tags

This is a new one on me.

In FF 3.6.3, use of the word 'script' in a tag id seems to make the id return null when searched on with `document.getElementById`.

Thus `document.getElementById("blah_script")` returns `null` from `<div id="blah_script"></div>`.

Understood that 'script' in general is a reserved word, but I didn't know it was so spooky that a mass-adopted browser would care if it was in a tag id with a preceding expression for disambiguation.

Comment: Works for me in 3.6.3.  What's your Firefox version and DOCTYPE?

Comment: Make sure that the code calling `getElementById` is running *after* the `<div>` shows up in the DOM.

Comment: I'm quite sure Pointy is right about the real problem. I can't imagine Firefox introducing this "you can't use the word 'script'" behavior. This answer may be useful for background if he is right (caveat: yes, it's one of mine): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920129/can-i-run-javascript-before-the-whole-page-is-loaded/2920207#2920207

Comment: Pointy called this correctly- otherwise the return would be an error, not 'null'

Comment: It ticks me off when people ask a question and abandon it