# Javascript - Detect page reload before document was fully loaded

Tags: javascript

I'd like to find out if a user presses F5 in a web browser before the page was fully loaded. I would like to use this as an indicator to find out if the page load time was too high for the user.

Is there a possibility?

Thanks much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run javascript before the whole page is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920129/can-i-run-javascript-before-the-whole-page-is-loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the before unload event and save info somewhere:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
     //save info 
});
```

just notice, that this event will invoke when you close the browser as well.

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery you can do something like this

```
var pageLoaded = false;

$(window).load(function(){
   pageLoaded = true;
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
  if (!pageLoaded && e.keyCode == 116)
         alert("f5 pressed before page fully loaded");
});
```