# can we clear sessionStorage before html on load

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me to know how i can clear sessionStorage before my HTML onload event call? I want to clear al the data stored in sessionStorage before my html rendered

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920129/can-i-run-javascript-before-the-whole-page-is-loaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I run javascript before the whole page is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920129/can-i-run-javascript-before-the-whole-page-is-loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the `sessionStorage.clear()` before the entiry HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            sessionStorage.clear();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HTML -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean sessionStorage exists before browser rendered html page?

Comment: It should. Try it.