# VueJS " new Vue()" in .js file not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I just started progamming with VueJS, and I can not understand the reason why I cannot put my "new Vue ()" function in a .js file.
I make an example with the simplest application I can think about.
If my HTML goes like this

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>HBL</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="esterno.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="application">
     <greeting></greeting>
  </div>
</body>
```

And my .js like this

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
template: '<h1>Basic Component</h1>'
});

var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#application'
 });
```

It does not show anything, the console displays this error :"[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #application", but if I open JSFiddle and just paste the code it works.

If I take the last three lines of the .js file and put them in a < script > tag in the html body, I have no error and everything works well.

Why does this happen? 
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `esterno.js` is the js code that you show, this is because

[the javascript code is executed before the DOM is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920129/can-i-run-javascript-before-the-whole-page-is-loaded)
 . You're right that putting the code below in the `<body>` tag will make sure that the code is only executed once the DOM, and therefore the element with id `application`, is loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew I was doing something wrong but I couldn't figure it out, now everything looks so obvious

Answer (score 2):

Scripts should be at the end of `body`. And I recommend you to load scripts when DOM is loaded.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>HBL</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="application">
     <greeting></greeting>
  </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="esterno.js"></script>
</body>
```